# idempotent function

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Assume $f\in C^1(\mathbb{R}^m,\mathbb{R}^m)$ satisfies $f\circ f=f$ ,and there exists $x_0\in\mathbb{R}^m$ s.t. $det f'(x_0)=0$.How to prove $f(x)=x$?

I have some ideas about it, like try to prove it is a injection, or use Banach fixed point thm, but have no idea for the details.

Comment: Sorry, but $f(x)=x$ does not have singular Jacobian matrix at any point.

Answer (score 1):

If $J$ is the Jacobian matrix at some point, then $J\cdot J = J$ by the chain rule.  So $J$ is an $m\times m$ matrix with minimal polynomial dividing $x^2-x = (x-1)x$.  Since the minimal polynomial splits into distinct linear factors, it follows that $J$ is diagonalizable with eigenvalues $0$ or $1$ along the diagonal.

Now, if $J$ is non-singular at every point that means its diagonalization is the identity matrix.  That implies it **is** the identity matrix.  So $f$ is the identity function $f(x) = x$.

It's possible however that $J$ has singular points.  For example if $P$ is any linear projection on a proper subspace, it satisfies $P^2 = P$.

Comment: however $det J$ is not non-singular on $\mathbb{R}^m$ ,it is only non-singular on $x_0$ :(